# whats app web campo personalizado para el telefono

Tags: php, whatsapp, href

Quiero agregar en PHP el href del link de whats app y el numero de telefono completarlo con un campo personalizado. Lo llamo $tel. No logro conseguirlo, me aparece el siguiente error, pueden ayudarme? esta bien el planteo?

```
<?php
$tel = get_field('telefono');
var_dump($tel);


if( $tel ): ?>

<a class="button" href="<?php echo http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$tel;?>">Enviar Whats App</a>  // line 153 

<?php endif; ?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /home/c1300927/public_html/home/wp-content/themes/startit/startit/single.php
>   on line 153 (yellow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra forma de hacerlo, y que evitará la *horrible* mezcla de código PHP/HTML que produce un código que hace mal a la vista, sería concatenar una sola variable e imprimirla al final.

Esto evitará la constante apertura/cierre de bloques PHP que hacen el código realmente difícil de analizar. Aquí todo se hace dentro de un solo bloque de código PHP.

```
<?php

$tel = get_field('telefono');
$html=""; //Vamos a concatenar con esta variable
if( $tel ) {
    $html.='<a class="button" href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone='.$tel.'">Enviar Whats App</a>';
}else{
    $html.="No tiene teléfono"; //Esto es opcional
} 
echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: Si el código mezclado genera problemas en futuros cambios, lamento que se mostrara como algo ilegible, la intención es acercarme lo mas posible a la programación original de la fuente. Pero apoyo completamente tu idea :)

Comment: Entiendo @RubenHernandez, mi respuesta es únicamente para mostrar otra forma de hacerlo, y que el código sea más legible. Esto es algo sencillo, pero hay programas en los que se requiere mucha mezcla de PHP/HTML y es un verdadero dolor de cabeza leer ese código mezclado.

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos!!